# Dot net exe rename error in server

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

We are using "VB .Net" programs installed in server which is running Windows server 2003 R2. We can rename ".Net" exe files in server even if those files kept open in client PCs which are running on Win XP and Win8.
But when the program is kept open in Win7 PC, we are not able to rename the exe on server.
We have checked the same in windows server 2008 R2 also. If we close those files in client or by closing openfiles in server, we can rename it.
We have checked the same by disabling antivirus in client pc, re installing OS to client etc.
But problem not resolved.
Please help

Comment: I'm not sure what you are going for. You will not be able to rename an executing program on a desktop PC. You are able to rename it server side because when a client executes it does not establish a lock on the server, but the client instance of the application will likely fail right after you rename it.

Comment: This sounds like a permission problem with nothing specific about the .NET Framework.  What error do you recieve when you attempt to change the name of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Windows is supposed to make sure that no-one else is using a file before you can make changes to it. Failing to do so can lead to your client's looking for a file that it no longer there in your particular case and version conflicts more generally.

The fact that you need to do this on a regular basis suggests that you need to be scheduling maintenance windows to make changes to your files or you need a test server that is separate from your main one.

However, if you have confirmed that no-one is using the file and it is still locked, you can unlock it from the server using the **Share and Storage Management** tool.

1. Click Manage Open Files
2. Click your file.
3. Click Close.

[Source](http://www.basics.net/index.php/2010/04/30/unlocking-shared-files-on-windows-2008-r2-server/)